# How to limit signed int with AND operator in C?

Tags: c

How to limit signed int with AND operator in C?
e.g.

```
signed int i = -300;
signed int j = i & 0x1F; -> expected value -31
```

Is it possible this way? If not, which is the simplest?

Update:
is it possible to clamp a signed integer within a given range using the & operator? If not what is the simplest method?

Comment: Expected value: 20. How would you ever get -31 from that?

Comment: Indeed, you removed the sign bit.

Comment: your question is not clear to me.

Comment: -31 needs at least 6 bits to store. You're masking it to only 5 bits, how can you get the correct value?

Comment: `int` is *at least* 16 bits, so `-300` will have a 2's complement bit pattern of `0xf ... ed4`. Consider the lower 8 bits: `0b11010100 & 0b11111  = 0b10100 = 0x14 = 20`

Comment: Rephrasing your question: *is it possible to clamp a signed integer within a given range using the `&` operator? If not what is the simplest method?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what you want to achieve. Masking the low bits while keeping the sign bit is something you could do with a single mask on architectures where `int` is represented as sign / magnitude. It is quite unlikely that you would be thinking of this peculiar case. What is your goal then ?

Be aware that masking is not the same as limiting the range. Except in the most trivial cases, limiting the range cannot be achieved with masking (the trivial cases being limiting to `0..0` and limiting to `INT_MIN..INT_MAX`)

If you just want to limit the range use this:

```
int j = i < -31 ? -31 : i > 31 ? 31 : i;
```

You can substitute any `int` values for minimum and maximum. `i` is evaluated twice in this expression: if you substitute a complex expression, it better to use a temporary variable. In some cases, the compiler can generate code without jumps for these tests, forget trying to do this by hand.